# Sum of times object

Tags: r, sum, chron

I just was faced with the problem, that I want to add up times in a time object, but the standard stuff (`colSums`, `sum`, `rowSums`) isn't working.

So, I have

```
time<-c("00:00:01", "01:02:00", "09:30:01", "14:15:25")
library(chron)
x <- chron(times=time)

x
[1] 00:00:01 01:02:00 09:30:01 14:15:25
```

How can I now add up all times in `x`?

Comment: given the answer below, maybe you can explain "isn't working" more precisely ...

Answer (score 4):

`sum(x)` works well for me

```
sum(x)
Time in days:
[1] 1.032951
```

Comment: Ouh great, I just figured out why I always got the `Error in sum(x) : method not defined for times argument` error. The `matlab` packages was loaded. After detaching it, it works fine.

Comment: @ Pascal, that's great you figured it out.  Maybe post your discovery as an answer, that way if someone comes across this question in google a year from now, the answer will be more readily available